# sum of the $n$ first $k$-th power considered as a polynomial in $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

Please explain the part with red lines...Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polynomial having infinitely many roots in a field is the zero polynomial (a non zero polynomial $P$ has at most $\deg P$ roots)

Comment: is that if a polynomial i a zero polynomial, it will hold for all numbers?

Comment: Plus, could you please prove that theory? Many thanks

Comment: For the proof, you can check
http://planetmath.org/apolynomialofdegreenoverafieldhasatmostnroots
For your particular problem, consider the polynomial $Q(x)=P_k(x)-P_k(x-1)-x^k$. It has infinitely many roots, so the expression $P_k(x)-P_k(x-1)-x^k$ is always zero.